# Don't process code part after clicking to a link

Tags: php, wordpress

There are two menus in my ask to expert page (ask-to-your-expert.php). When a user selects an expert, the page redirects him/her to a page on which user can ask a question to that expert (ie: ?doctor-id=5). What I want is to remove that two menus in specific expert pages. I don't want the select expert menus to be visible to users in specific expert pages. How can I exclude them in expert pages?

Thanks.

Comment: are you looking to exclude menu item for particular page only using wp_nav_menu

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) that removes the menus and apply it to you doctors profile pages.

[is_page_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) might be useful to you.

Comment: I am afraid that does not work for me. Is there any way to manage this by using PHP coding?

Comment: There is a page in page list in wordpress and that page is using php file. In that php file there are 2 hardcoded menus. I don't want them to be visible to users after selecting an expert. It is not possible using a page template.

Comment: okay, can you do it using an `if` statement and the `get_the_title()` method?